# how to add custom id to url in submit input in php

Tags: php, input, submit

i want to add id to url, when i click the submit button. For example:

```
<form action="MyBasket.php">{
<select id="selectBeden" name="D1">
..
</select>
<select id="selectAdet" name="D2">
..
</select>
}
<input type ="submit" value="Submit" />
```

i want to pass these selections to MyBasket.php but also, i should pass the id like this: MyBasket.php?id=//id_from_db

So how can i customize the url with input submit ?

Comment: What is the `id_from_db`? Is not in the code you posted, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe one thing first: Work on your accept rate! That is, go to questions you have asked in the past an mark the corresponding answer!

Now to your question... I assume your form is part of the output of a php script in which you retreive the `id_from_db` from the database?

If so, I would suggest using a hidden input field in which you will put your ID:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $id_from_db; ?>" />
```

BUT you can never really trust this information, because the value of the field can be changed by the user! If you want to have more safety, store the ID in a session variable...

Comment: sorry i cloudnt understand what should i do for my questions:(
and yes id_from_db is the id from my database and it changes according to the selected product.